# Select all child records against specific id in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have many records in task table with parent_id. 
Like

```
 task_id name parent
   1      a     0
   2      b     1
   3      c     2
   4      d     3
   5      e     0
   6      f     5
```

I have task_id 1 in my shared table so I want to  select it and its all child record till nth level.
I have this query

```
SELECT 
    shared.task_id,tsk.* 
FROM 
    tbl_sharedtasks shared, tbl_tasks tsk 
WHERE 
    shared.user_id=1 AND tsk.task_id=shared.task_id.shared
```

suppose 1

But this select only one record. Problem is that this should select First and task_id 1 have a child record task_id 2 and 2 have 3 parent and 3 have 4 parent. so these all should select all which have relation with parent

Comment: if it is supposed to select one then what is the problem here ?

Comment: Problem is that this should select First and task_id 1 have a child record task_id 2 and 2 have 3 parent and 3 have 4 parent. so these all should select

Comment: Yes. This is a standard problem with hierarchical data in mysql.

Comment: so what will be the solution?

Comment: so what will be the solution?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve a tree? Look into nested sets. http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: The article I linked to has a section on nested sets. Some RDBMS (like Oracle) have built-in functionality for that, by MySQL does not. You'll have to store the tree information in table columns and build your queries against that.

Comment: If you're going to have an arbitrary depth, say four, you can left join the table against itself four times. The article I linked to shows that at well.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support selecting recursively, but you can do it in your app code with more queries, however, this may cause performance issue if your task table goes large. Consider change your design.

Answer (score 0):

This is done through create function first in Mysql as below

```
DROP FUNCTION `taskLevel`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `taskLevel`(GivenID  int(11)) RETURNS varchar(1024)    CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE lvl varchar(10);
DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children,front_id VARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE queue_length,pos INT;
SET rv = '';
SET queue = GivenID;
SET queue_length = 1;

WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
    SET front_id = queue;
    IF queue_length = 1 THEN
        SET queue = '';
    ELSE
        SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) + 1;
        SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
        SET queue = q;
    END IF;
    SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;

    SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
    FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(task_id) qc
    FROM tbl_tasks WHERE parent_id = front_id) A;

    IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
        IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
            SET queue_length = 0;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
            SET rv = queue_children;
        ELSE
            SET rv = CONCAT(rv,',',queue_children);
        END IF;
        IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
            SET queue = queue_children;
        ELSE
            SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
        END IF;
        SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
    END IF;
END WHILE;

RETURN rv;
END

SELECT  `task_id` ,  `title` , taskLevel(`task_id`) AS children FROM tbl_tasks WHERE  `task_id` =1
```